# Android Button doesn't change colour on click

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, background-color, android-drawable

When I click on a particular button, the button background's colour is suppose to change while the other buttons remain in its default colour. However, upon running the app, the button doesn't change its colour though the rest of the logic in the code works well. I still can't figure out what's wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timer_test);

  adult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdult);
    peer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPeer);
    material = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMaterial);
    physical = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhysical);


    //Set button disabled, when new activity is turned on

    flag.setEnabled(false);
    alarm = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    ...

OnClickListener codes :

if (textDemo.getText().toString() == "Record") {
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  if (v.equals(physical)) {
               // do something
              physical.setText("PHYSICAL ON CLICK WORKS");
              physicalPrompt = "Yes";
              physical.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.buttonPressed));
              adult.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
              peer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
              material.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
 }

   else if (v.equals(material)) {
               // do something
               material.setText("MATERIAL ON CLICK WORKS");
               materials = "Yes";
               material.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.buttonPressed));
               peer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
                adult.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
                physical.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
  }

    else if (v.equals(peer)){
                peer.setText("PEER ON CLICK WORKS");
                peers = "Yes";
                peer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.buttonPressed));
                physical.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
                adult.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
                material.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);

 }

    else if (v.equals(adult)){
                 adult.setText("ADULT ON CLICK WORKS");
                 peers = "Yes";
                 peer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.buttonPressed));
                 physical.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
                 adult.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
                 material.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);

 }

    else {
                // do something else
                textDemo.setText("Error!");
         }
    }
   };

   physical.setOnClickListener(listener);
   material.setOnClickListener(listener);
   peer.setOnClickListener(listener);
   adult.setOnClickListener(listener);
   }
  }
 }
```

In value/colors.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name="buttonNotPressed">#2196F3</color>
<color name="buttonPressed">#1976D2</color>

<!--<color name="colorHighlightFAB">#B6B6B6</color>-->
<color name="ColorPrimary">#E91E63</color>

</resources>
```

Extra Codes :

```
public class Timer_Test extends ActionBarActivity {

//Declare widgets
Button buttonStart, flag, back, timeButton, adult, peer, material, physical;
TextView timerTextView, tvTest, interval, child, status, id, session,  
passName, tvStartTime, textDemo;
```

Comment: It might be beneficial to show a little more code; such as where the button variables are declared and assigned.

Comment: Did you try this - button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.your_color);?

Comment: and try moving this code - `physical.setOnClickListener(listener);
   material.setOnClickListener(listener);
   peer.setOnClickListener(listener);
   adult.setOnClickListener(listener);` to your onCreate() method.

Comment: @Varundroid yes i tried this line too

Comment: Did you also move the above code to onCreate() method ?

Comment: Ok then let me put the recommended way of doing this in answer and that should work for you just fine.

Comment: are you able to change the text of buttons?

Comment: Yes I am able to change the text. I will try your answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution first and let me know if its working -

```
private View.OnClickListener mFirstListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        ((Button)v).setText("New Text");
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mSecondListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        ((Button)v).setText("New Text");
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mThirdListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        ((Button)v).setText("New Text");
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mFourthListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_blue);
        ((Button)v).setText("New Text");
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button1.setOnClickListener(mFirstListener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(mSecondListener);
    button3.setOnClickListener(mThirdListener);
    button4.setOnClickListener(mFourthListener);
}
```

***Recommended way (Using XML only) -***

Create a file inside your drawable folder called button_states and put the following code in -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/buttonPressed" /> <!--Pressed State-->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/buttonPressed" /> <!--Focused State-->
    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" /> <!--Normal State-->
</selector>
```

Now in your xml set the button background like this -

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:padding="10dp"
        **android:background="@drawable/button_states"**
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"/>
```

And then you don't need to change the colours in code at all and it will work fine for you.

If you use recommended way get rid of this line from all listeners - `v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);` but for text change you still need to keep the following line `((Button)v).setText("New Text");`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you use recommended way get rid of this line from all listeners - `v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);` but for text change you still need to keep the following line `((Button)v).setText("New Text");`

Answer (score 0):

Mine didn't work because I had `exitFadeDuration` and `enterFadeDuration` set:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="40"
    android:enterFadeDuration="120">
```

After removing it, all was good!

Answer (score -1):

Buttons are more complex than just changing one color...

Android buttons are made using quite a few 9-patches and state drawables. Simply trying to set a background color might not reset previously set resource styles. Try creating another state drawable resource with changed background color and assigning it to the button.

Comment: But if you have a look at the question you linked to, you'd see that the OP of that question was asking something entirely different.